# Using .sendkey inside an HTA. Telnet does not receive Escape

Tags: hta, sendkeys

I am trying to write an HTA that uses a command shell and the .sendkeys function to manipulate Telnet.  I have everything working, save for the fact that Telnet does not receive my escape key!  I have tried as many formatting options as I can think of.  I have also started Telnet with the "-e N" argument to simplify the escape sequence, but my chosen character just gets echo'd to the terminal instead of being interpreted as an escape key.

The part that is confusing me is that it works as a wsh script, but not when the code is run from an HTA.

```
Sub TestCmd
On Error Resume Next
//Dim WshShell
set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "cmd.exe"
//WshShell.AppActivate "cmd"
Sleep 1
WshShell.Sendkeys "telnet.exe 130.160.176.219 4998 -e z {enter}"
Sleep 1
WshShell.SendKeys "sendir,1:1,1,37764,1,1,340,168,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,4833"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
Sleep 1
WshShell.SendKeys "sendir,1:1,10,37764,1,1,340,168,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,4833"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
Sleep 1
WshShell.SendKeys "sendir,1:1,5,37764,1,1,340,168,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,4833"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
Sleep 1
WshShell.SendKeys "sendir,1:1,11,37764,1,1,340,168,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,4833"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
Sleep 1
WshShell.SendKeys "sendir,1:1,1,37764,1,1,340,168,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,4833"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
Sleep 1
WshShell.SendKeys ("^{]}q{Enter}exit{Enter}")
End Sub
```